# Automating retrieval of page metrics from Facebook

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

What would be a recommended strategy for automating the retrieval of page metrics from facebook?

My first approach was to create a C# app to retrieve the page metrics.  However, when the application authorizes itself using the SDK's FacebookOAuthClient.GetApplicationAccessToken() method, the access token returned from this function does not have sufficient privileges to retrieve information about the pages I'm interested in.

I would prefer not to write an application that someone has to log in to on a daily basis.

Is there any way to grant page privileges to an application, or is there a better strategy?

Answer (score 0):

Have you read this: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

If you haven't done so, you will have to register you application on Facebook too. Go to developers: http://developers.facebook.com/?ref=pf and then apps at the top.

Comment: I've read that article and in my first approach I have successfully registered my metrics retrieval application which is a console application.  What am I'm missing from the http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ article.  Please advise.  

For my second attempt I'll build  a mini-site to login a user, get a permanent (off-line) user token, and save the token for use by the first application.  Ideally, I'd just prefer to have the app token work to retrieve the pages of interest, but either something in my config  or the user token / app token / page token scheme is impeding me.

Comment: The owner of the pages has to authorize your application to access the insights data. Also, you might have to make the account associated with the application a page administrator of the page you're interested in. The scope=offline_access privilege doesn't require the user to log in daily. Note that you can separate the access_token from your C# code by making get calls in your browser, ie: https://graph.facebook.com/insights/...?access_token=...

Comment: John, thanks immensely!!! 

I'll try this.  (Saves me from writing yet another App.)

Comment: I get "An error occured, please try again later." from the OAuth dialog.

Comment: Is the redirect_uri necessary? I don't have a web app at this point.

Comment: Achieved success with the following redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html

Comment: Chiat - if this solved your problem could you select the answer as having solved your problem? This helps other users who are experiencing the same problem.

Comment: Oops! Your answer (viz. the complete solution) couldn't be submitted because:

We're sorry, but as a spam prevention mechanism, new users can only post a maximum of two hyperlinks. Earn more than 10 reputation to post more hyperlinks.

Comment: The person that thought of the spam prevention policy was a very limited thinker.